# What is the supossed scope for translating file format to SFV?

Tags: authorization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Im going along with the tutorial from: 
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/

and i got stuck with translating the file to SVF. I've tried data:write, data:create, bucket:update scopes but each time I get:

Token does not have the privilege for this request.

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "someUrn="
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf",
                "views": [
                    "2d",
                    "3d"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need both `data:read and (data:write or data:create)` (delimited by space) - see doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#resource-information):

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate'
  -X 'POST'
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  -d '
    client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&
    client_secret=eUruM8HRyc7BAQ1e&
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    scope=data:read%20data:write
  '
```

And did you select Model Derivative API when creating the Forge app - if not, start over and create the app again:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, 
I've run also with some different translation errors, but it turns out .rfa files are not supported in the Model Derivative API.

But all in all it worked out